Error during upload of a custom policy xml file for sending emails via sendgrid
Im trying to upload my B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Extensions custom policy. But I keep getting this upload error:

this is my xml file:
    <TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" 
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="test.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Extensions" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://test.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Extensions">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>test.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="otp">
        <DisplayName>Secondary One-time password</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="emailRequestBody">
        <DisplayName>SendGrid request body</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="VerificationCode">
        <DisplayName>Secondary Verification Code</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Enter your email verification code</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="subject">
        <DisplayName>Email subject</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="message">
        <DisplayName>Email message</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="codeIntro">
        <DisplayName>Email code introduction</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="signature">
        <DisplayName>Email signature</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetLocalizedStringsForEmail" TransformationMethod="GetLocalizedStringsTransformation">
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="subject" TransformationClaimType="email_subject" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="message" TransformationClaimType="email_message" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="codeIntro" TransformationClaimType="email_code" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signature" TransformationClaimType="email_signature" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateEmailRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.to.0.email" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="subject" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.subject" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.otp" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.email" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="message" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.message" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="codeIntro" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.codeIntro" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signature" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.signature" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <!-- TBD <InputParameter Id="template_id" DataType="string" Value="yoursendgridtemplateid"/> -->
          <InputParameter Id="template_id" DataType="string" Value="d-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
          <InputParameter Id="from.email" DataType="string" Value="servicedesk@OMMITED.COM" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.en" />
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.es" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.en" />
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.es" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
    <Localization Enabled="true">
      <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
        <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
        <SupportedLanguage>es</SupportedLanguage>
      </SupportedLanguages>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.custom-email.en">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <!--Email template parameters-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_subject">Contoso account email verification code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_message">Thanks for validating the account</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_code">Your code is</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_signature">Sincerely</LocalizedString>
          <!-- Display control sign-up UI elements-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="intro_msg">Verification is necessary. Please click Send button.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="success_send_code_msg">Verification code has been sent to your inbox. Please copy it to the input box below.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="failure_send_code_msg">We are having trouble verifying your email address. Please enter a valid email address and try again.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="success_verify_code_msg">E-mail address verified. You can now continue.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="failure_verify_code_msg">We are having trouble verifying your email address. Please try again.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="but_send_code">Send verification code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="but_verify_code">Verify code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="but_send_new_code">Send new code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="but_change_claims">Change e-mail</LocalizedString>
          <!-- Display control password reset UI elements-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="intro_msg">Verification is necessary. Please click Send button.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="success_send_code_msg">Verification code has been sent to your inbox. Please copy it to the input box below.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="failure_send_code_msg">We are having trouble verifying your email address. Please enter a valid email address and try again.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="success_verify_code_msg">E-mail address verified. You can now continue.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="failure_verify_code_msg">We are having trouble verifying your email address. Please try again.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="but_send_code">Send verification code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="but_verify_code">Verify code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="but_send_new_code">Send new code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="but_change_claims">Change e-mail</LocalizedString>
          <!-- Claims-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="emailVerificationCode" StringId="DisplayName">Verification Code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="emailVerificationCode" StringId="UserHelpText">Verification code received in the email.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="emailVerificationCode" StringId="AdminHelpText">Verification code received in the email.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="email" StringId="DisplayName">Email</LocalizedString>
          <!-- Email validation error messages-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfSessionDoesNotExist">You have exceeded the maximum time allowed.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfMaxRetryAttempted">You have exceeded the number of retries allowed.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfInvalidCode">You have entered the wrong code.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfSessionConflict">Cannot verify the code, please try again later.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfVerificationFailedRetryAllowed">The verification has failed, please try again.</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </LocalizedResources>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.custom-email.es">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <!-- Email validation error messages-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_subject">Código de verificación del correo electrónico de la cuenta de Contoso</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_message">Gracias por comprobar la cuenta de </LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_code">Su código es</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_signature">Sinceramente</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </LocalizedResources>
    </Localization>
    <DisplayControls>
      <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <Actions>
          <Action Id="SendCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
          <Action Id="VerifyCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
        </Actions>
      </DisplayControl>
      <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationSSPRControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        </InputClaims>
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims></OutputClaims>
        <Actions>
          <Action Id="SendCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-CheckEmailAddressExists" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp">
                <Preconditions>
                  <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                    <Value>objectId</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                  </Precondition>
                </Preconditions>
              </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
          <Action Id="VerifyCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
        </Actions>
      </DisplayControl>
    </DisplayControls>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>One time password technical profiles</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="GenerateOtp">
          <DisplayName>Generate one time password</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">GenerateCode</Item>
            <Item Key="CodeExpirationInSeconds">60</Item>
            <Item Key="CodeLength">6</Item>
            <Item Key="CharacterSet">0-9</Item>
            <Item Key="ReuseSameCode">true</Item>
            <Item Key="NumRetryAttempts">2</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" PartnerClaimType="otpGenerated" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="VerifyOtp">
          <DisplayName>Verify one time password</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">VerifyCode</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" PartnerClaimType="otpToVerify" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>RestfulProvider</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SendOtp">
          <DisplayName>Use SendGrid's email API to send the code the the user</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">emailRequestBody</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BearerAuthenticationToken" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SendGridSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateEmailRequestBody" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetLocalizedStringsForEmail" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
          </DisplayClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-CheckEmailAddressExists">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Reset Password</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetLocalizedStringsForEmail" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationSSPRControl"/>
          </DisplayClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
        <OrchestrationSteps>
            <!-- Existing CombinedSignInAndSignUp Step -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
                <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
                </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 2: Registration Step if user is not registered -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <Preconditions>
                    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                        <Value>objectId</Value>
                        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                    </Precondition>
                </Preconditions>
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 3: Generate OTP -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="GenerateOtpExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 4: Send OTP -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="SendOtpExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 5: Prompt User to Enter OTP and Verify -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="VerifyOtp" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 6: Fetch User Attributes if not already done -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 7: Issue Token -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
        </OrchestrationSteps>
        <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>

What am I doing wrong here?
[Edit]
I got that fixed now, but the next error message I get from app insights is this:

Exception Message:A partner claim with id 'identifier' is not found however is required in technical profile 'GenerateOtp' in policy 'B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Signin' of tenant 'OMMITED.onmicrosoft.com'., Exception Type:InvalidReferenceException, CorrelationID:6012857a-a210-4844-bf2b-6ac01a82fe1b

And this is the details of the same message:

[{"outerId":"0","message":"Exception Message:A partner claim with id 'identifier' is not found however is required in technical profile 'GenerateOtp' in policy 'B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Signin' of tenant 'OMMITED.onmicrosoft.com'., Exception Type:InvalidReferenceException, CorrelationID:6012857a-a210-4844-bf2b-6ac01a82fe1b","type":"System.Exception","id":"63019560"}]

What am I missing here in my xml file?

Problem could be merging of data with the base policy. Try changing the user journey Id to something other than "SignUpOrSignIn". It could be merging steps from the base policy together and creating a step with more than one ClaimsExchange.

Okay, should i change this:  in the relying party too than? So that it will match for example SignUpOrSignInV2 if i change it to that?

Yeah, you should change that as well.

@juunas, thanks that fixed the error, I've edited my question with a new error, an exception from app insights. Any chance you know what the error means exactly?

Quoter, FYI
By having the error message the value for the partner claim with id 'identifier' is not available , it is primarily due to none of the inherited policy [Base or Extensions] provides the value of email claim from the orchestration step 1. Thus failing on sending the email via sendgrid as GenerateOTP technical profile (TP) input claim is null [partner claim identifier in your policy]. If I understand correctly, as you are using SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email TP for signin, then copy the signInName to email by inherit them with ClaimsTransformation as below
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName"/>
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopySignInToEmailClaim"/>
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>

<ClaimsTransformation Id="CopySignInToEmailClaim" TransformationMethod="CopyClaim">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
    </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>

Update 23-Dec-24:Linking the related conversation A partner claim with id 'identifier' is not found however is required in technical profile for reference. @quoter hope u would resolve these both issues

I do have that claim in the base file. I hosted all the 4 xml files in one paste on this website: https://pastebin.com/2V3aYite

Yes @Quoter i gone thro' the policies and You do have that email claim but i was referring that the value was not provided from SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email profile. To give you more insights in which flow are your facing this error bcoz you referred generate OTP profile in both SignIn n SignUp flow. I was suspected that error happened in signin flow [where claim value was missed] hence provided my thoughts that if you copied the signin claim value to email claim before invoking GenerateOTP profile to resolve the error in signin journey. Could u confirm once whether signin/up

Im trying to sign in. So an existing account trying to authenticate and after that receiving the OTP code to login. Sign up is the next step.

Hi, here is the solution for sign in with 2FA, Inherit the TechnicalProfile (SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email)  along with ClaimsTransformation (CopySignInToEmailClaim) to carry value to email claim thus further be used in generate otp. Also few retrospection on your policies: - Claims (otp n verificationCode) should be case sensitive - MFA should be carried thro' the conventional display claims. Applied those changes on your policy

Hi Mohamed, very nice, this got me finally to the next screen. The OTP verification screen. The email has been send too. But the OTP code wasnt in the email. So somehow the generating OTP code hasn't been sent, or maybe not even created. i used your xml code. Any idea what its missing?

Glad to receive the progress, Hoping you updated the ClaimsTransformation GenerateEmailRequestBody based on your Email template design like the doc described here. The provided one is based on my env setup.

Yes I have, im using a template created in sendgrid portal. I'm receiving the template and everything, but its not populating the {{email}} and {[otp}} in the template upon receiving the email. So I'm missing something in the xml file.

Hi i was able to get the OTP code by changing this line: personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.otp from code at the end to otp. But the email address is not being passed in, in the username property in the backend.

Hi, if I understood correctly, you are expecting the JWT claim as username in the token which will be further used in your backend?

Yes, it contains 4 properties including username. But that claim is empty.

I know it's out of the context of this question,  but to complete your project need, here is the gap.. it should be added as output claims in ur policy B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Signin with partner Claim as SignInName.

JWT will produce only the claims described in the RelyingParty of your policy B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Signin, if you want username,  u can add it by referring with partner Claim type as SignInName. Hope this sounds good to complete your project needs n this thread :)

Its already claimed in the relying party, this is the list: 




 still empty email. Its also not showing up in the html template via sendgrind in my mail. It starts with "Dear  ," while it should show something like "Dear Mohamed,"...

this didnt work either: 

Hi quoter, for ask#2, to get the username as output claim, 

Hi Mohamed, I added the username too as claim, and i add that line you gave me in the RP. But now in stead of asking username/password, its asking username/signin name in the input fields.

Hi Quoter, was bit occupied in year end.. Plz ignore my previous comment as there was a conflict and try this one line in your RP. No more claims declaration is needed for username as it's part of JWT. It's been tested in my local as follows. {
"sub": "",
"aud": "",
"acr": "",
"nonce": "defaultNonce",
"iat": 1733398231,
"auth_time": 1733398231,
"userName": "abc@xyz.com",
"email": "abc@xyz.com",
"name": "abc@xyz.com",
"tid": ""
}
